# Android Studio Kotlin activity doesn't show elements at runtime

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, mobile

I'm building my first android app through android studio using kotlin, and I'm having issues with the elements of an activity showing up when I run the app.

I created a button in the main activity that navigates to the new activity, and inside the new activity is a prompt for a text input.

However, the new activity is just blank when ran.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CalcActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="651dp"
        android:text="Enter Polynomial Fraction"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display3"
        android:textColor="#435768"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/poly_edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="107dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="167dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="579dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textLongMessage"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btn_click_me = findViewById<Button>(R.id.CalcButton)
        // set on-click listener
        btn_click_me.setOnClickListener {
            // your code to perform when the user clicks on the button
            val intent = Intent(this, CalcActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }


}
```

```
package com.example.prac

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText

class CalcActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc)

    }
}
```

Comment: You should post the CalcActivity class and its layout file as it seem that the problem is there?

Comment: Please share your "new activity.kt" file

Comment: My mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why hard-coding `margin` with big values this will not work on all screen sizes also you need to know how to use `contraintlayout` this is a [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html) to `codelab` also this is a working sample for your code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout                                                
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Enter Polynomial Fraction"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display3"
    android:textColor="#435768"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/poly_edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textLongMessage"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView2"
    />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I should've posted code myself, but I just didn't think to. I'm just frustrated by this project is all. My apologies everyone.

Comment: No problem ,you are welcome, all of us face the same situation when beginning to learn